# What does 「はった」 mean?

Tags: translation

I heard this phrase in a video 「はったはった」, and I am only guessing that it *might* be the verb 「張る」. It passes in a rap verse so I can't really think of a context to give other than that our rapper is a gambler. To cut it short, can 「はった」 mean "bet" or "place your bets"?

I also found 「切った張った」, but I am pretty sure that's not it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can't provide the source for actual context I'm not sure what good other random guesses will do.

Comment: It seems like the question was perfectly answerable, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In gambling, 「張{は}る」 indeed means "***to place one's bet***".  See definition #24 in [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BC%B5%E3%82%8B-605454), which says:

> 24 賭(か)け事などに金銭をかける。「相場を―・る」

「賭{か}け事{ごと}」 means "gambling".

Next, an explanation of the "***verb + た***" to express an order/request might be in order (no pun intended) as that is not something I have heard too many Japanese-learners use. This た is ***not*** the past-tense た.

Definition #4 for 「た」 in [明鏡国語辞典](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/%E6%98%8E%E9%8F%A1%E5%9B%BD%E8%AA%9E%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/prefix/%E3%81%9F) says:

> ❹ 《終止形{しゅうしけい}で》差{さ}し迫{せま}った要求{ようきゅう}・命令{めいれい}を表{あらわ}す。
>   「さあ、帰[かえ]っ━、帰っ━」
>   「おっと待[ま]っ━」

That says: (in plain form) expresses an imminent order or request.

As you see in the first example 「帰った、帰った。」, we often repeat the verb.  「張った、張った！」 is indeed very common in gambling.  One would rarely say just 「張った！」.

「さあ、帰った、帰った。」 has the nuance of "Get the hell outta here!"

「おっと待った。」 means "Hey, wait a sec!"

Finally, the expression that you mentioned 「切{き}った張{は}った」 has nothing to do with what we are talking about.  It means "being very violent", "slashing and striking", etc.

「キットカット」 has nothing to do with it, either.

Comment: 帰った、帰った isn't always such offensive, though lacking politeness for sure.

Comment: I never said it was offensive.  "Get the hell outta here!" is not always all that offensive.